# How to install redmine with Chef

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, redmine

I try to install Redmine via APT and Chef but it does not work.

I always get the error

```
Could not find gem 'rails (~> 4.2.7)' in any of the gem sources listed in your
Gemfile.
```

It seems to be Chef related because the same apt command works when execute it by myself.

Here is the output of Chef:

```
[2019-02-27T17:47:35-05:00] WARN: *****************************************
[2019-02-27T17:47:35-05:00] WARN: Did not find config file: /root/.chef/chef.rb, using command line options.
[2019-02-27T17:47:35-05:00] WARN: *****************************************
[2019-02-27T17:47:35-05:00] WARN: No cookbooks directory found at or above current directory.  Assuming /root.
[2019-02-27T17:47:35-05:00] FATAL: Cannot load configuration from nodes/redmine.json
root@debian:~# cd chef-repo/
root@debian:~/chef-repo# chef-client -z -j nodes/redmine.json -c .chef/chef.rb
Starting Chef Client, version 14.10.9
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["my-redmine"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - my-redmine (1.0.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: my-redmine::default
  * apt_package[redmine] action install

    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `install` on resource 'apt_package[redmine]'
    ================================================================================

    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
    ------------------------------------
    Expected process to exit with [0], but received '100'
    ---- Begin output of ["apt-get", "-q", "-y", "--allow-downgrades", "-o", "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef", "-o", "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold", "install", "redmine=3.3.1-4+deb9u2"] ----
    STDOUT: Reading package lists...
    Building dependency tree...
    Reading state information...
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      dbconfig-common dbconfig-sqlite3 fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core
      fonts-droid-fallback fonts-lato fonts-noto-mono ghostscript gsfonts
      imagemagick-6-common javascript-common libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data
      libavahi-common3 libcups2 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libcurl3
      libfftw3-double3 libfontconfig1 libgomp1 libgs9 libgs9-common libijs-0.35
      libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 libjpeg62-turbo libjs-coffeescript libjs-jquery
      libjs-source-map libjs-uglify liblcms2-2 liblqr-1-0 libltdl7
      libmagickcore-6.q16-3 libmagickwand-6.q16-3 libopenjp2-7 libpaper-utils
      libpaper1 libruby2.3 libtiff5 libuv1 libxslt1.1 libyaml-0-2 nodejs passenger
      poppler-data rake redmine-sqlite ruby ruby-actionmailer ruby-actionpack
      ruby-actionpack-action-caching ruby-actionpack-xml-parser ruby-actionview
      ruby-activejob ruby-activemodel ruby-activerecord ruby-activesupport
      ruby-addressable ruby-arel ruby-atomic ruby-binding-of-caller
      ruby-blankslate ruby-builder ruby-bundler ruby-byebug ruby-coderay
      ruby-coffee-rails ruby-coffee-script ruby-coffee-script-source
      ruby-columnize ruby-concurrent ruby-css-parser ruby-debug-inspector
      ruby-did-you-mean ruby-erubis ruby-execjs ruby-ffi ruby-globalid ruby-hike
      ruby-hmac ruby-htmlentities ruby-i18n ruby-jbuilder ruby-jquery-rails
      ruby-json ruby-listen ruby-loofah ruby-mail ruby-mime-types ruby-mimemagic
      ruby-minitest ruby-molinillo ruby-multi-json ruby-net-http-persistent
      ruby-net-ldap ruby-net-telnet ruby-nokogiri ruby-oj ruby-openid
      ruby-pkg-config ruby-polyglot ruby-power-assert ruby-protected-attributes
      ruby-rack ruby-rack-openid ruby-rack-test ruby-rails
      ruby-rails-deprecated-sanitizer ruby-rails-dom-testing
      ruby-rails-html-sanitizer ruby-rails-observers ruby-railties ruby-rb-inotify
      ruby-rbpdf ruby-rbpdf-font ruby-redcarpet ruby-request-store ruby-rmagick
      ruby-roadie ruby-roadie-rails ruby-sass ruby-sass-rails ruby-sdoc
      ruby-spring ruby-sprockets ruby-sprockets-rails ruby-sqlite3 ruby-test-unit
      ruby-thor ruby-thread-safe ruby-tilt ruby-treetop ruby-turbolinks
      ruby-tzinfo ruby-uglifier ruby-web-console ruby2.3 rubygems-integration
      sqlite3 unzip zip
    Suggested packages:
      fonts-noto ghostscript-x apache2 | lighttpd | httpd cups-common libfftw3-bin
      libfftw3-dev coffeescript liblcms2-utils libmagickcore-6.q16-3-extra
      passenger-doc rails poppler-utils fonts-japanese-mincho
      | fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-japanese-gothic | fonts-ipafont-gothic
      fonts-arphic-ukai fonts-arphic-uming fonts-nanum bzr cvs darcs mercurial
      ruby-fcgi subversion ri ruby-dev ruby-builder-doc doc-base treetop bundler
      sqlite3-doc
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      dbconfig-common dbconfig-sqlite3 fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core
      fonts-droid-fallback fonts-lato fonts-noto-mono ghostscript gsfonts
      imagemagick-6-common javascript-common libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data
      libavahi-common3 libcups2 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libcurl3
      libfftw3-double3 libfontconfig1 libgomp1 libgs9 libgs9-common libijs-0.35
      libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 libjpeg62-turbo libjs-coffeescript libjs-jquery
      libjs-source-map libjs-uglify liblcms2-2 liblqr-1-0 libltdl7
      libmagickcore-6.q16-3 libmagickwand-6.q16-3 libopenjp2-7 libpaper-utils
      libpaper1 libruby2.3 libtiff5 libuv1 libxslt1.1 libyaml-0-2 nodejs passenger
      poppler-data rake redmine redmine-sqlite ruby ruby-actionmailer
      ruby-actionpack ruby-actionpack-action-caching ruby-actionpack-xml-parser
      ruby-actionview ruby-activejob ruby-activemodel ruby-activerecord
      ruby-activesupport ruby-addressable ruby-arel ruby-atomic
      ruby-binding-of-caller ruby-blankslate ruby-builder ruby-bundler ruby-byebug
      ruby-coderay ruby-coffee-rails ruby-coffee-script ruby-coffee-script-source
      ruby-columnize ruby-concurrent ruby-css-parser ruby-debug-inspector
      ruby-did-you-mean ruby-erubis ruby-execjs ruby-ffi ruby-globalid ruby-hike
      ruby-hmac ruby-htmlentities ruby-i18n ruby-jbuilder ruby-jquery-rails
      ruby-json ruby-listen ruby-loofah ruby-mail ruby-mime-types ruby-mimemagic
      ruby-minitest ruby-molinillo ruby-multi-json ruby-net-http-persistent
      ruby-net-ldap ruby-net-telnet ruby-nokogiri ruby-oj ruby-openid
      ruby-pkg-config ruby-polyglot ruby-power-assert ruby-protected-attributes
      ruby-rack ruby-rack-openid ruby-rack-test ruby-rails
      ruby-rails-deprecated-sanitizer ruby-rails-dom-testing
      ruby-rails-html-sanitizer ruby-rails-observers ruby-railties ruby-rb-inotify
      ruby-rbpdf ruby-rbpdf-font ruby-redcarpet ruby-request-store ruby-rmagick
      ruby-roadie ruby-roadie-rails ruby-sass ruby-sass-rails ruby-sdoc
      ruby-spring ruby-sprockets ruby-sprockets-rails ruby-sqlite3 ruby-test-unit
      ruby-thor ruby-thread-safe ruby-tilt ruby-treetop ruby-turbolinks
      ruby-tzinfo ruby-uglifier ruby-web-console ruby2.3 rubygems-integration
      sqlite3 unzip zip
    0 upgraded, 144 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 48.9 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 170 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 libruby2.3 amd64 2.3.3-1+deb9u4 [3110 kB]
    Get:2 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 fonts-droid-fallback all 1:6.0.1r16-1.1 [1807 kB]
    Get:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 ruby2.3 amd64 2.3.3-1+deb9u4 [188 kB]
    Get:4 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 fonts-lato all 2.0-1 [2684 kB]
    Get:5 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 liblqr-1-0 amd64 0.4.2-2+b2 [24.8 kB]
    Get:6 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 libgomp1 amd64 6.3.0-18+deb9u1 [73.3 kB]
    Get:7 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 libfftw3-double3 amd64 3.3.5-3 [731 kB]
    ...
    ...
    ...
    Get:144 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 zip amd64 3.0-11+b1 [234 kB]
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    Fetched 48.9 MB in 32s (1505 kB/s)
    Selecting previously unselected package fonts-droid-fallback.
(Reading database ... 41787 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../000-fonts-droid-fallback_1%3a6.0.1r16-1.1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking fonts-droid-fallback (1:6.0.1r16-1.1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package fonts-lato.
    Preparing to unpack .../001-fonts-lato_2.0-1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking fonts-lato (2.0-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package liblqr-1-0:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../002-liblqr-1-0_0.4.2-2+b2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking liblqr-1-0:amd64 (0.4.2-2+b2) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libgomp1:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../003-libgomp1_6.3.0-18+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libgomp1:amd64 (6.3.0-18+deb9u1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libfftw3-double3:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../004-libfftw3-double3_3.3.5-3_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libfftw3-double3:amd64 (3.3.5-3) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package fonts-dejavu-core.
    Preparing to unpack .../005-fonts-dejavu-core_2.37-1_all.deb ...
    Unpacking fonts-dejavu-core (2.37-1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package fontconfig-config.
    Preparing to unpack .../006-fontconfig-config_2.11.0-6.7_all.deb ...
    Unpacking fontconfig-config (2.11.0-6.7) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libfontconfig1:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../007-libfontconfig1_2.11.0-6.7+b1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libfontconfig1:amd64 (2.11.0-6.7+b1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libjbig0:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../008-libjbig0_2.1-3.1+b2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libjbig0:amd64 (2.1-3.1+b2) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libjpeg62-turbo:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../009-libjpeg62-turbo_1%3a1.5.1-2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libjpeg62-turbo:amd64 (1:1.5.1-2) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package liblcms2-2:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../010-liblcms2-2_2.8-4+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking liblcms2-2:amd64 (2.8-4+deb9u1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libltdl7:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../011-libltdl7_2.4.6-2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libltdl7:amd64 (2.4.6-2) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libopenjp2-7:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../012-libopenjp2-7_2.1.2-1.1+deb9u2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libopenjp2-7:amd64 (2.1.2-1.1+deb9u2) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libtiff5:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../013-libtiff5_4.0.8-2+deb9u4_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libtiff5:amd64 (4.0.8-2+deb9u4) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package imagemagick-6-common.
    Preparing to unpack .../014-imagemagick-6-common_8%3a6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u6_all.deb ...
    Unpacking imagemagick-6-common (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u6) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libmagickcore-6.q16-3:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../015-libmagickcore-6.q16-3_8%3a6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u6_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libmagickcore-6.q16-3:amd64 (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u6) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libmagickwand-6.q16-3:amd64.
    Preparing to unpack .../016-libmagickwand-6.q16-3_8%3a6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u6_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libmagickwand-6.q16-3:amd64 (8:6.9.7.4+dfsg-11+deb9u6) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package poppler-data.
    Preparing to unpack .../017-poppler-data_0.4.7-8_all.deb ...
    Unpacking poppler-data (0.4.7-8) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package dbconfig-common.
    Preparing to unpack .../018-dbconfig-common_2.0.8_all.deb ...
    Unpacking dbconfig-common (2.0.8) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package sqlite3.
    Preparing to unpack .../019-sqlite3_3.16.2-5+deb9u1_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking sqlite3 (3.16.2-5+deb9u1) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package dbconfig-sqlite3.
    Preparing to unpack .../020-dbconfig-sqlite3_2.0.8_all.deb ...
    Unpacking dbconfig-sqlite3 (2.0.8) ...
    ...
    ...        
    ...
    Setting up ruby-builder (3.2.2-4) ...
    Setting up ruby-activemodel (2:4.2.7.1-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-jbuilder (2.3.1-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-sprockets (3.7.0-1+deb9u1) ...
    Setting up ruby-bundler (1.13.6-2) ...
    Setting up ruby-rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3-2) ...
    Setting up ruby-activerecord (2:4.2.7.1-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-rails-dom-testing (1.0.6-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-activejob (2:4.2.7.1-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-rack-openid (1.4.2-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-protected-attributes (1.1.3-2) ...
    Setting up ruby-rails-observers (0.1.2-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-actionview (2:4.2.7.1-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-actionpack (2:4.2.7.1-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-actionpack-xml-parser (1.0.2-2) ...
    Setting up ruby-actionmailer (2:4.2.7.1-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-railties (2:4.2.7.1-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-sprockets-rails (2.3.2-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-roadie-rails (1.1.0-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-actionpack-action-caching (1.1.1-4) ...
    Setting up ruby-jquery-rails (4.2.1-2) ...
    Setting up ruby-coffee-rails (4.1.0-2) ...
    Setting up ruby-rails (2:4.2.7.1-1) ...
    Setting up redmine (3.3.1-4+deb9u2) ...
    Could not find gem 'rails (~> 4.2.7)' in any of the gem sources listed in your
    Gemfile.
    dpkg: error processing package redmine (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Setting up ruby-sass-rails (5.0.6-1) ...
    Setting up ruby-web-console (2.2.1-2) ...
    Setting up ruby-turbolinks (2.5.3-3) ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     redmine
Extracting templates from packages: 100%ckages: 20%
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
    ---- End output of ["apt-get", "-q", "-y", "--allow-downgrades", "-o", "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef", "-o", "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold", "install", "redmine=3.3.1-4+deb9u2"] ----
    Ran ["apt-get", "-q", "-y", "--allow-downgrades", "-o", "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef", "-o", "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold", "install", "redmine=3.3.1-4+deb9u2"] returned 100

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /root/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/my-redmine/recipes/default.rb

     20: package 'redmine' do
     21:   action :install
     22: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /root/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/my-redmine/recipes/default.rb:20:in `from_file'

    apt_package("redmine") do
      package_name "redmine" 
      action [:install]
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      declared_type :package
      cookbook_name "my-redmine" 
      recipe_name "default" 
    end

    System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=14.10.9
    platform=debian
    platform_version=9.8
    ruby=ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]
    program_name=/usr/bin/chef-client
    executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client

Running handlers:
[2019-02-27T17:48:38-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2019-02-27T17:48:38-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 59 seconds
[2019-02-27T17:48:38-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /root/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2019-02-27T17:48:38-05:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2019-02-27T17:48:38-05:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: apt_package[redmine] (my-redmine::default line 20) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '100'
---- Begin output of ["apt-get", "-q", "-y", "--allow-downgrades", "-o", "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef", "-o", "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold", "install", "redmine=3.3.1-4+deb9u2"] ----
```

Answer (score 0):

before you try to install a package, you should make sure that your package manager has updated its repository.

> It seems to be Chef related because the same apt command works when execute it by myself.

did you execute `apt update` before running the `apt install` command?
if so, you have to make sure that your cookbook does that too and you can do that by using [`apt_update`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_apt_update.html) resource